# How to correlate data to take command actions with awk?

Tags: awk

I have been trying to do something after work with multiple .csv files; merging ones that have the same key id to a final file with two columns.
i.e.

```
col1 col2
a     b
x     y
```

and I want, in base of this data, read row by row, and correlate this result to create folders and subfolders, according each row.

i.e

`mkdir -p a/b` taken count about relationship between the row that contains this values.

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: awk is for manipulating text, not creating/destroying files/directories/processes/etc. - that's what a shell is for. By trying to use awk for that you open yourself up to all sorts of insidious bugs and nasty security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you want but here is something you can work on

```
$ awk 'NR>1{system("mkdir -p "$1"/"$2)}' file

$ tree
.
├── a
│   └── b
├── file
└── x
    └── y

4 directories, 1 file
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: well, if this is it, perhaps just using `bash` might be better.

Comment: You'd better pray the input only contains alphanumeric characters if you run that script since it's not even quoting the strings being passed to `mkdir`. Even if you fix that problem there are others lurking that you just can't fix. I wouldn't do it.